# Drinfeld-Jimbo quantum groups for $q=0$

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

In the [Wikipedia page of Drinfeld--Jimbo quantum groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) the values of $q=0,1$ are excluded so as to avoid dividing by zero. The $q=1$ case is discussed in this [old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126461/quantized-enveloping-algebras-at-q-1). What about the $q=0$ case? Is it also possible to define the dual quantum coordinate algebra $\mathcal{O}_q(G)$ for $q=0$?

Comment: Perhaps one of these are "crystal quantum groups"? Google that.

Answer (score 4):

Hong & Kang's book on Crystal bases (*Introduction to quantum groups and crystal bases, AMS Graduate Studies in Mathematics, vol 42*) which describes the work of Kashiwara and Lusztig is a good place to start.
In short, $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ does not exist as a Hopf algebra at $q=0$, but one can talk about $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$-modules at $q=0$. Kashiwara had also dealt with the algebra of coordinate functions $\mathcal{O}_q(G)$ at $q=0$ in his paper
*Global crystal bases of quantum groups. Duke Math. J., 69(2):455–485, 1993*. For a treatment of the coordinate function algebras at the $C^*$-algebra level, you can take a look at the following two papers:

1. Manabendra Giri and Arup Kumar Pal. Quantized function algebras at $q = 0$: type $A_{n}$ case. arXiv:2203.14665 [math.QA], 2022.
2. Marco Matassa and Robert Yuncken. Crystal limits of compact semisimple quantum groups as higher-rank graph algebras, 2022. arXiv:2208.13201 [math.QA], 2022.